# AsyncTask refreshing google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, handler, scheduledexecutorservice

My android application retrieves some json data from remote API for each Marker (a Marker shows the position of a real device, there are less than 10 devices to watch) present on the map, and sets status of a device by changing a color of the marker according to some rule working on a given json data. I use AsyncTask to fetch json data and change a status of a device. I keep fetched data in `ConcurrentHashMap<Device, Data>`. So, I run a number of asynctasks, one for each device. I also use a custom info window (in fact custom InfoWindowAdapter) to show some more data about device. First I draw a markers and keep them in a map `HashMap<Device, Marker>`. I execute asynctasks one by one using:

```
new MyAsyncTask(markerMap).execute(device)
```

My custom InfoWindowAdapter overrides getInfoContents method, where some collected by asynctasks data are used to be shown in InfoWindow, when clicked.
Everything works fine. But now I want to refresh my markers every 10 sec. I have tried to do it using the following approach:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

    @Override
    public void run() {

        new MyAsyncTask(markerMap).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, device1);
        new MyAsyncTask(markerMap).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, device2);

    }}, 0, 10000);
```

My question is if it is the right/ best way to refresh my map? Or should I use Runnable instead of AsyncTask, and within a Runnable send a message to Handler when fetching json data to update Marker? One more question: should I use Timer or ScheduledExecutorService? I have read some StackOverflow discussions but I dont know the final recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: As per my Opinion Go with `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` is best in your case.

Comment: But I can not close the question. An asynctask should be started from the main thread. A timer is run in separate thread. So, I can not be sure if my onPostExecute method will be performed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved my problem. In mean time I have rewritten part of my program in order to use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with subclassed `Runnable` (instead of `Asynctask`). In addition I have added onResume() method where I restart `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` using: `mScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`